# Remove Band items in Raster layer Legend item

Tags: qgis, legend

Creating a legend for a project that has a raster layer, and I cannot work out how to remove the Red Green Blue band display in the Legend.

[image: Raster Legend Item]

QGIS 3.28

Answer (score 1):

you can use a placehoder image instead: Layer properties -> legend

[image]